# How to make a 600MHz loop on arduino or Raspberrypi?

Tags: c++, loops, arduino, raspberry-pi, frequency

I need a pulse to be generated 600 million times a second either on Arduino or Raspberrypi boards. My purpose is to measure the distance between a transmitter and a receiver. The receiver counts the received pulses in every second and estimates the distance. In which ways can i write the code?

Comment: What is the pulse for? Why does it need to be that high frequency? A hardware solution is probably better to create such a high-frequency pulse with good reliability.

Comment: An Arduino Uno works with 16 MHz. It's not possible to do this in software with an Arduino Uno.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I submited more details.

Comment: @ThomasSablik What about Raspberrypi-3? Its CPU has a frequency of 1.2 GHz

Comment: What is your exact hardware? There are many different Arduinos and Raspberry Pis with different specs? How do you read the signals?

Comment: @ThomasSablik The signal is sent and received by wifi modules(ESP8266)

Comment: ESP8266 works with 80 MHz (default) or 160 MHz

Comment: @ThomasSablik Ok, i'll search for a full suitable harware and ask my question again. Thanks

Comment: If you have two computers that are time-synched using a clock with high enough precision then you don't need to send pulses with that high frequency. All you really need is a *single* pulse.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In that case, I guess a nanosecond timer will be needed too, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you ask is not possible with Arduino or Raspberry Pi due to their clock frequencies.
Arduino Uno has 16MHz, Raspi 1.2GHz.

You would need a lot more than 600MHz to create pulses at 600MHz.

To create a pulse in a loop you would have to turn an output HIGH and then LOW. A single digitalWrite in Arduino (AVR) takes about 60 clock cycles. So HIGH/LOW is about 120. Respectively the highest frequency you could generate would be something around 130KHz.

Take a look into clock generator ICs or crystal oscillators.

Comment: An Arduino can generate higher frequencies than that, if you access the port register directly instead of using digitalWrite. It still can't go up to 600MHz.

Comment: I suspect it is not possible on *any* currently available microcontroller. @user12530749 will need to build some circuits.

Comment: @user253751 of course but we were talking Arduino here, not AVR registers. you're still magnitudes away from what you want

Comment: You can set AVR registers when writing code using the Arduino IDE. It's routinely done, for speed or because the Arduino library is missing a feature.